# How can I prevent #REF errors in Excel when connecting to Databricks through ODBC?

Tags: excel, odbc, databricks, powerquery, azure-databricks

I've got an excel file that connects to Azure Databricks using an ODBC connection. My goal is to be able to open the excel file, hit "Refresh All" on the data tab, and have the newest data in my excel report on its own sheet called "Data". Occasionally (and I cannot recreate this error), when I reference that "Data" sheet, I get a #REF! error that does not go away even after refreshing the data again.

Does anybody know what causes this, and you help me take steps to prevent this?

In case it matters, the "Data" sheet always has the same number of rows and columns.

I've searched Youtube and Google for answers, but I've not been able to find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

> **#REF! error caused by deleting a Rows or Columns in Excel**

**Two Ways You Can Solve Ref Error**

1. if you accidentally deleted rows or columns, you could Immediately click **CTRL Z**
2. Adjust the formula so that it uses a range reference instead of individual cells, Example like =**SUM(B2:D2)** ,if you delete any column in this range automatically adjusted.

“Refresh All” and connect to Databricks through ODBC it Works fine.

**You can follow this Reference:**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-ref-error-822c8e46-e610-4d02-bf29-ec4b8c5ff4be